# handling nested json in looping

Tags: php, json

json after json_encoded

```
 {
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"JIN",
         "id":"100007934492797"
      },
      {
         "name":"aris",
         "id":"100008128873664"
      },
      {
         "name":"Madm",
         "id":"34234234"
      }
   ],
   "paging":{
      "next":"https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/1380314981/friends?limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_AeyRMdHJrW0kW9vIZ41uFPXMPgE-VwRaHtQJz2JWyVc0hMl9eOG10C6JWjoCO8O2E4m24EPr28gIt9mxQR8oIQmN"
   }
}
```

I want to store the name and ID of my json in db. But when I use for loop there's a problem with the offset, I suspect it's the last part of the json. How to remove the paging part? I tried

```
foreach($friends as friend){
    echo friend[0]->name;
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is invalid since you're missing `$` for `friend`.  Seems like you should be doing `foreach ($friends->data as $stores)`

Comment: when I do json_encode($friends->data) it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you use `json_decode($json)` or `json_decode($json, true)`?

Comment: @Barmar what is the different?

Comment: The first decodes JSON objects as PHP objects, the second uses associative arrays.

Comment: @Barmar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971532/loop-through-fb-api-friends-got-error

Comment: That doesn't help. We can't tell from the JSON whether the original `$user_friends` was an associative array or an object. They both get encoded the same way.

Comment: Please show `var_dump($user_friends)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, your original code would never work:

```
foreach($friends as friend){
echo friend[0]->name;
}
```

Those references to `friend` should have `$` in front of them making them `$friend`. Then to solve your larger issue, just use a nested `foreach` loop:

```
$json = <<<EOT
{
  "data": [
        {
          "name": "JIN", 
          "id": "100007934492797"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "aris", 
          "id": "100008128873664"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Madm", 
          "id": "34234234"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/1380314981/friends?limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_AeyRMdHJrW0kW9vIZ41uFPXMPgE-VwRaHtQJz2JWyVc0hMl9eOG10C6JWjoCO8O2E4m24EPr28gIt9mxQR8oIQmN"
      }
}
EOT;

$friends = json_decode($json);

foreach($friends as $friend_data){
  foreach($friend_data as $friend){
    echo $friend->name . '<br />';
  }
}
```

And the output of this would be:

```
JIN
aris
Madm
```

Additionally, if working with arrays makes more sense for you, you can always set `json_decode` to return an array by setting the second parameter to `true`. Here is refactored code as an example:

```
$friends = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($friends as $friend_data){
  foreach($friend_data as $friend_key => $friend_value){
    if (isset($friend_value['name'])) {
      echo $friend_value['name'] . '<br />';
    }
  }
}
```